# Customizing Meteor Package useraccounts:materialize

Tags: meteor

I'm currently trying to use the `useraccounts:materialize` package from Atmosphere; however, I do not know how to customize the HTML and CSS of it.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps :

1. Fork/Clone this [repo](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/materialize)
2. Make the required changes to the html and css files in the directory `/lib`
3. Publish your package to atmosphere and use that if you want to make it public OR use this as a local package.

Read about publishing to atmospherejs [here](https://atmospherejs.com/i/publishing) and about using it as a local package by placing the package under `packages` folder in root and running the command `meteor add usrname:packagename`